# Convert Sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

hey everyone i want to convert this sql query into linq query. but i have some problem i dont know how to solve it please help me..

my sql query

```
select SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.id,site.Name, SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.countrycode, sum(SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRYDETAILS.estddays) as estddays
from SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY
inner join site on SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.SiteId = site.id
inner join SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRYDETAILS on SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.id = SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRYDETAILS.servicelasbycountrykey
where SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.servicecode = 234
group by SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRYDETAILS.servicelasbycountrykey,site.Name, SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.countrycode,SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRY.id
```

this is tried by me but its have some error please help me to remove this.

```
from s in db.SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRies
                               join si in db.sites on s.SiteId equals si.id
                               join sd in db.SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRYDETAILs on s.id equals sd.servicelasbycountrykey 
                               where s.servicecode == servicecode
                               group sd by sd.estddays into bhh 
                               select new SLACountryDTO                        
                               {
                                   ID = s.id,
                                   ServiceCode = s.servicecode,
                                   CountryCode = s.countrycode,
                                   SiteId = s.SiteId,
                                   SiteName = si.Name,
                                   Sum = bhh.Sum(sd => sd.estddays)
                               });
```

error is

```
"s" does not exist current context 
"si" does not exist current context
```

Comment: What error does it have?

Answer (score 2):

Just like how you have done the `grouping` in your SQL query you need to do in your LINQ query as well like this:-

```
from s in db.SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRies
      join si in db.sites on s.SiteId equals si.id
      join sd in db.SERVICESLASBYCOUNTRYDETAILs on s.id equals sd.servicelasbycountrykey 
      where s.servicecode == servicecode
      group sd by new { sd.estddays, s.countrycode,s.servicecode,s.id,s.SiteId,si.Name } 
                  into bhh 
      select new SLACountryDTO                        
      {
           ID = bhh.Key.id,
           ServiceCode = bhh.Key.servicecode,
           CountryCode = bhh.Key.countrycode,
           SiteId = bhh.Key.SiteId,
           SiteName = bhh.Key.Name,
           Sum = bhh.Sum(sd => sd.estddays)
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bhh group has a Key and a Collection of items, you should go through this object to get the data. s & si are not valid in the context of your group